# chrome extension use the same socket.io connection under background page and content scripts

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, socket.io

I'm doing a chrome extension with socket.io , i have a content script that keep connecting to server to make a real-time chat, but i also want to get some information from server in background page. it works well separately like this

in content script

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3700');
socket.on('dosomething',function(){
  console.log("test");
});
```

in background page

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3700');
socket.on('dosomething',function(){
  console.log("test");
});
```

but is there any way to only connect one time and when server have something like

app.js  `socket.emit('dosomething');`

and will trigger either background page or content script which has   `socket.on('dosomething')`  ?

I've tried sending the socket established by background page to content script by using
`chrome.runtime.sendMessage`  and  `chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener` ,

but it didn't work :(

Is there any solution?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I tried to write a socket.io client in content script which will send message to background page when socket.io server send "hello" request.

**Content Script:**

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:1337');
socket.on("hello",function(data){
    console.log(data.text);
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({msg:"socket",text:data.text},function(response){});
});
```

**Background page:**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request,sender,senderResponse){
        if(request.msg==="socket"){
            console.log("receive from socket server: "+request.text);
        }
    }
);
```

**Server side:**

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler).listen(1337);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);

function handler(req,res){
    console.log(req.url);
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':'text/plain'});
    res.end('Hello Node\n You are really really awesome!');
}

io.sockets.on('connection',function(socket){
    socket.emit('hello',{text:"node!"});
});
```

**Screen shot of background console:**

[image]

Hope this is helpful for you.