# Chrome Extension Socket io node js

Tags: node.js, google-chrome-extension, socket.io

I need to create a chrome extension which shows a notification when we get a message from socket io node js server.

How to include socket io in chrome extension? I am not able to get this to working.

Content.js:- **Uncaught ReferenceError: io is not defined**

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:1337');
socket.on("hello",function(data){
    console.log(data.text);
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({msg:"socket",text:data.text},function(response){});
});
```

**Manifest:- This is not importing socket io**
Failed to load extension from: 
Could not load background script 'http://localhost:1337/socket.io/socket.io.js'.

```
    "background": {
    "scripts": [
        "http://localhost:1337/socket.io/socket.io.js",
        "background.js"
    ]
},
```

node server.js

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler).listen(1337);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);

function handler(req,res){
    console.log(req.url);
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':'text/plain'});
    res.end('Hello Node\n You are really really awesome!');
}

io.sockets.on('connection',function(socket){
    socket.emit('hello',{text:"node!"});
});
```

Comment: Can you simply include a static file in the extension, or does it need to be generated each time from the server?

Comment: When ever there is a socket emit from server I need to show a notification in chrome extension.

Comment: What does it have to do with the JS file?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17805140/chrome-extension-use-the-same-socket-io-connection-under-background-page-and-con    I am trying the solution given by chickenrice, but not sure how to import socket io in chrome extension

Comment: Simply put: it's hard (not impossible, but hard) to make Chrome load an external file as a script. Do you _really_ need to, or can you simply add `socket.io.js` to the extension?

Comment: Ok let me try adding socket io in the extension. Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81655/discussion-between-dinesh-jeyasankar-and-xan).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since you only need the socket.io-client, this is what you should be doing:

```
"background": {
  "scripts": [
    "socket.io.js",
    "background.js"
  ]
},
```

Download and add the socket.io.js file from here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Automattic/socket.io-client/1.3.5/socket.io.js

Comment: It's not a good idea to point to a tip-of-the-tree version of a library, especially in a client-server architecture. One should look at a release appropriate for your server-side code, e.g. here: https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io-client/releases

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I couldn't find the releases last time for some reason.

Comment: @RahatMahbub i get error socket.io.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Answer (score 3):

Note in 2020:

Rahat's answer is fine except the socket version , when you use it in background script it always reconnects , so if you use inappropriate version of socket.io.js you 'll get something like this
[image]

but with socket.io.js 2.3.0 worked correctly as it should
[image]
here is a link which worked for me https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/socket.io-client@2/dist/socket.io.js

More info at https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io-client

Comment: Thank you for the exact versioning. Above answer did worked, but there are n number of connections being established. There might be the version issue. Again thanks.

Comment: How can we do it in v3

Comment: @RakshitJoshi I think people are doing it now.  Here's a link I found detailing ports and mv3: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/developer.chrome.com/issues/2688